# How to create such a line automatically?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.5, self

In the iteration, I have 10 files from which I choose the appropriate elements for the simulation. Then I need to create an appropriate line that will be automatically loaded into another program.

And I have something like this:

```
class MyLoop(loopmodel):
   def select(self):
      return select(MY LINE)
```

and MY LINE should look like this:

```
self.residues['18:A'],self.residues['19:A'], ...
```

'18: A '- this is generated by another script from my files and each of the 10 files has a different number of these values

How can I create 10 different lines of this type automatically?

(Python 3.5)

Comment: Is this meant to be a recursive function? I don't see a base condition defined here that would allow it to ever finish executing. More importantly, please provide the actual output and/or error that you're getting. That would be tremendously helpful in diagnosing your issue.

Comment: I have no error or result because I can't make self.residues automatically because it can't be in quotes.

Comment: What is `self.residue`? A `dict`?

Comment: these are formulas to be executed by the program for the given parentheses. I can generate these lines but they are str () and I need to have it without the quotes which is self.residues () and not 'self.residues ()'.

Comment: MYLINE = tuple([self.residues['%d:A'%n] for n in range(start, end)])

Comment: (@qwwe) you are defining MYLINE as a tuple (collection of values) to be returned. 
self.residues['18:A'] with string is indexing an dictionary with key '18:A'
If this a spreadsheet, ie. line 18, column A?  Ie. 2 dimensional list?  If so then you need to use self.residual[18][columnPosition].

Comment: 18: A is generated from a text file and immediately comes as '18: A '(structure number in protein and protein chain).